# Github actions repository redirect

Tags: github-actions

When a repository name changes , github auto redirects the repository

eg: `https://github.com/nick-invision/retry`  will auto redirect to `https://github.com/nick-fields/retry`

But when used in an action as such

```
      - name: Validate version number (domain)
        uses: nick-invision/retry@v2.6.0
        with:
          timeout_seconds: 20
          max_attempts: 15
          retry_wait_seconds: 10
          command: |
            set -x
            IP=$(curl "https://something")
            echo $IP | grep ${{ github.sha }}
```

This fails with a repository not found.

Comment: Could you explain what is your issue, or what you want to achieve?

Comment: If the repository of action that is being used eg: nick-invision/retry@v2.6.0 , the owner changes name to nick-fields , the action fails. You would need to go and specifically change the uses to `nick-fields/retry` . It does not use the automatic github redirect on name changes .

Comment: I understood the problem, but what do you expect us to help you with? If the problem is with the action, it would probably be better to open an ISSUE on the related github repository, wouldn't it?

Comment: Did not make it clear though, my bad . Wanted to know if there was anything specific to do to allow redirects. But did raise it on github.community - seemingly where github wants to direct issues to . 

DOes not seem to belong to the https://github.com/actions/runner . Or will raise it there as well .